# Invalid Column Name in SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql, sql-server

When I execute this query in SQL Server Management Studio, this error appears:

```
'Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
 Invalid column name 'ACCOUNT_NO'.'
```

This is the code for the query:

```
DECLARE @largeaccnumber INT = ACCOUNT_NO
DECLARE @smallaccnumber INT
SET @smallaccnumber = (SELECT LEFT(@largeaccnumber, 6))  
SELECT DNADRX.CODE, 
       DNADDR.NAME,
       DNADDR.TYPE, 
       DNADDR.MAIL_NAME,
       ADDRESS_LINE1, 
       ADDRESS_LINE2, 
       ADDRESS_LINE3, 
       TOWN_CITY, 
       COUNTY_STATE, 
       COUNTY_STATE_CODE, 
       COUNTRY, 
       POST_ZIP, 
       LAST_STAT_DATE, 
       ACCOUNT_NO
FROM DNADRX,
     DNADDR,
     BACCNT          
WHERE DNADDR.CODE = DNADRX.ADDRESS_CODE 
     AND DNADDR.CODE = @smallaccnumber 
ORDER BY DNADRX.CODE
```

I want the query to display the data from the columns of the different tables (the columns are listed in the SELECT bit of the query) from 3 different tables (DNADRX, DNADDR, BACCNT), and the factor linking all 3 tables together is the 6 digit code (ACCOUNT_NO in the BACCNT table, ADDRESS_CODE in the DNADRX table and CODE in the DNADDR table). Originally, ACCOUNT_NO from table BACCNT was 8 digits long, but I reduced it to the first 6 digits using SELECT LEFT and assigned this 6 digit value to the variable @smallaccnumber.

Whenever I try to execute the query, it keeps telling me that 'ACCOUNT_NO' is an invalid code name. I have checked the spelling, refreshed using IntelliSense and tried 'BACCNT.ACCOUNT_NO' instead of just 'ACCOUNT_NO' on the first line of the query but it still won't work (instead it says that the multi-part identifier could not be bound when I try 'BACCNT.ACCOUNT_NO').

I am really new to SQL coding so sorry if the answer to my problem is really simple.

Thank you for your assistance :)

Comment: `DECLARE @largeaccnumber INT = ACCOUNT_NO` this isn't valid syntax, you can't just create a variable and assign it a column from no table or anything at all

Comment: @Lamak ACCOUNT_NO is a column in the table BACCNT - I want to assign a value from this column to a variable (so I can make the number shorter, from 8 to 6 digits in length). 
I'm a little unsure as to what you mean by 'no table or anything at all' - there are many tables in the database, including the table BACCNT. 
Are you able to help me work out what the valid syntax to create the variable would be? Thank you very much :)

Comment: Assuming you have more than one row in `BACCNT`, which row do you want to use to assign a value to the variable?

Comment: I mean that your syntax says: `DECLARE @largeaccnumber INT = ACCOUNT_NO`, do you see a table there?, should SQL Server guess which table you want and what row of that table you want?

Comment: On an unrelated note, you are cross joining 3 tables but no condition for the `BACCNT` table in your `WHERE` conditions, so you are most likely producing an undesired cartesian product there (unless that table has only one row)

Comment: @GarethD Thank you for helping me spot that problem :) I want it to go through each row of that column and assign that value to the variable. Would a loop help me do this? (I was thinking maybe a For... Next loop with the row number being incremented by 1 each time).

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this.

This assumes you know the 6 character code.  This query will only find results IF there is a record matching in EVERY table.  If one table doesn't find a matching record this query will return NOTHING.  If you want to find a row even if a recrod is missing from a table, replace the "INNER JOIN" with "LEFT OUTER JOIN"

```
    SELECT Dnadrx.Code, 
       Dnaddr.Name, 
       Dnaddr.Type, 
       Dnaddr.Mail_Name, 
       Address_Line1, 
       Address_Line2, 
       Address_Line3, 
       Town_City, 
       County_State, 
       County_State_Code, 
       Country, 
       Post_Zip, 
       Last_Stat_Date, 
       Account_No
  FROM Dnaddr
       INNER JOIN BACCNT ON DNAADDR.CODE = BACCNT.ACCOUNT_NO
       INNER JOIN Dnadrx ON Dnaaddr.Code=Dnaadrx.Address_Code
 WHERE Dnaddr.Code='YOUR 6 CHARACTER CODE GOES HERE'
 ORDER BY Dnadrx.Code;
```